# How to solve the "ImportError: cannot import name 'control_flow_ops' from 'keras.backend.load_backend'"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have added this two lines in the **init**.py in C:\Users\xxy19\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\Lib\site-packages\keras\backend：

```
from .load_backend import control_flow_ops
from .load_backend import set_image_dim_ordering
```

But it still exists:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'control_flow_ops' from 'keras.backend.load_backend' (C:\Users\xxy19\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py)
```

How can I successfully use tensorflow-gpu? Is it actually the version compatibility problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.python.control_flow_ops = tf
```